# How to show that the stalk over p is a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, sheaf-theory, germs

We were given this information:

"A set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if for every $p \in U$ there exists an $\epsilon =\epsilon(p) > 0$ so that for every $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert y-x \rVert <0$ we have $y \in U$.

Let's say that $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $p$ if there exists $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\lim_{x \to p} \frac{f(x)-(\vec{a}\cdot x+b)}{\lVert x-p \rVert}.$$

The sheaf of differentiable functions refers to the canonical identification, $U \mapsto C^1(U)$ which identifies to each open set, $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the set of differentiable functions on that set, $C^1(U) := \lbrace f:U\to \mathbb{R} |f \text{ differentiable}\rbrace$. For a given point $p$, one can define an equivalence relation on $C(\mathbb{R^n})$ by $$f \sim g \text{ if there exists an open set } U \subset \mathbb{R^n} \text{so that} f\vert _U = g\vert _U.$$

The set of equivalence classes is referred to as the stalk over p and is denoted $\mathcal{O}(p)$.

Show that the stalk, $\mathcal{O(p)}$, is a vector space by proposing a well-defined addition and scaling operation, $\lambda [f] + [g] := [\lambda f + g]$."

I think I'm just not very clear on how to prove something is well defined, or even how to begin to consider this prove.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that addition is well defined, all you need to do is show independence of choice of representatives. That is, show that for differentiable functions $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$, defined around $p$, if $f_1\sim g_1$ and $f_2\sim g_2$, then $f_1+f_2\sim g_1+g_2$. For scalar multiplication you also need to perform a similar check.